# Manipulating an infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I want to show (or rather, know why) $$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{k^2}{k!} = 2e.$$ I have tried using the power series expansion for $e^x$, and also series manipulations with $\ln(x)$, but with no success. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{k^2}{k!}=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{k}{(k-1)!}=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{k-1}{(k-1)!}+\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{(k-1)!}=2\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{1}{k!}=\color{red}{2e}.$$

An alternative approach is the following one. Since:
$$\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{e^{kx}}{k!} = e^{e^x}-1, \tag{1} $$
we have:
$$ \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{e^{kx}}{k!}=\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{k^2 e^{kx}}{k!}=e^{x+e^x}+e^{2x+e^x}\tag{2}$$
and it is enough to replace $x$ with $0$.

Comment: My hat goes off to you.

Comment: @KevinSheng: no need of such formality, I am just glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

Recall that the expansion for $e^x$ is given by

$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}\tag 1$$

Differentiating $(1)$ and mulitplying by $x$ yields

$$xe^x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{nx^{n}}{n!}\tag 2$$

Differentiating $(2)$ and multiplying by $x$ yields

$$x(x+1)e^x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2x^{n}}{n!}\tag 3$$

whereupon setting $x=1$ reveals that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{2e=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{n!}}$$

Comment: General formulas are rather useful. Equation (3) can be used to show $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n} \, n^{2}}{n!} = 0$$

Comment: @Leucippus It's been a while.  Nice to see you returning.  And yes!  Upon inspection, it would not be an obvious evaluation ... not for me anyway.

Comment: Sometimes work gets in the way of fun.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\frac{k^2}{k!}=\frac{k}{(k-1)!}=\frac{1+(k-1)}{(k-1)!}$. You also need to pay attention at the beginning of the series as well.